# Adding data Neo4J database

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, import, neo4j, graph-databases

Recently started my first job as a graduate fresh out of university and have been put in charge of a project using unfamiliar technologies. I haven't worked with rolling out real world web apps before so apologies in advance if i'm barking up the wrong tree.

We currently have a web app deployed through AWS that currently can only have records added to it manually. The app uses Neo4J as the database which i have no experience with (or graph databases in general for that matter).

My question isn't so much a direct programming question so much as a set up question, essentially through what method would i be able to upload the data to the already existing web app? During have seen people using Cypher for inserts but am unsure how i would be able to utilise this on an already deployed web app? I also have the app locally running on my machine if it is necessary to make the changes and then re deploy if necessary.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[Cypher](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/) is the query language used for interacting with Neo4j (reading and writing). You can send Cypher queries to a Neo4j instance using a [driver](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/), from whatever language your application is using (Java, JavaScript, Python, etc).

What format is the data you want to upload? Since your question is tagged `csv`, if you have csv files you can use the `LOAD CSV` functionality built into Cypher to import data from csv files. For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///users.csv" As row
MERGE (u:User {name: row.name})
MERGE (c:City {name: row.city})
CREATE (u)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c)
```

I would suggest having a look at some of the developer guides specific to the [language you are working with](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/) and on [importing data](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/).

There is also the [Neo4j Browser](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/), which is a query workbench for Neo4j. It allows you to run Cypher queries through a web browser interface and visualize the results.